# GrooVY Sql :: how call a stored function that returns a ORACLE cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, groovy, cursor

I have a package

```
create or replace package core_utils is
  TYPE CONSULTA IS REF CURSOR;
  function getCursor(par in varchar2 default null) return core_utils.CONSULTA;

end core_utils;
create or replace package body core_utils is
     function getCursor(par in varchar2 default null) return core_utils.CONSULTA
     is 
        c  core_utils.CONSULTA;
    begin
       OPEN c FOR
        select d.aplicacio,d.nom       
        from variables_def d
        where d.global='S'
        and   d.nom like par
        order by d.nom;
        return c;
     end;
end core_utils;
```

the call will be like ..

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
import groovy.sql.Sql
 m=[:]
 ...
 m.sql =Sql.newInstance(m.url, m.username, m.password, m.driver)
 m.sql.call('{? = call core_utils.getCursor(?)}', [Sql.????? ,par]) { resu->
    //
    .............
    .............
  }
```

surely 'call' is not the procedure you should use. I have not found any examples that help me.

Comment: how would you call it from oracle pl/sql?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242512/how-to-get-cursor-from-oracle-using-groovy

Answer (score 0):

```
/**************************************

inspiration 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242512/how-to-get-cursor-from-oracle-using-groovy

plsql
--------------------------------------
begin
-- Call the function
:result := core_utils.getcursor(par => :par);
end;  
========================================================================
oracle

create or replace package core_utils is
 TYPE CONSULTA IS REF CURSOR;
 function getCursor(par in varchar2 default null) return core_utils.CONSULTA;
end core_utils;
----------------------------------------------   
create or replace package body core_utils is
    function getCursor(par in varchar2 default null) return core_utils.CONSULTA
     is 
        c  core_utils.CONSULTA;
    begin
       OPEN c FOR
        select d.aplicacio,d.nom       
        from variables_def d
        where d.global='S'
        and   d.nom like par
        order by d.nom;
        return c;
     end;
end core_utils;
========================================================================
*/
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
import groovy.sql.Sql
import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;
import groovy.sql.OutParameter;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
m=[:]
//@Grab('com.oracle:ojdbc7')

m.CURSOR_PARAMETER = new OutParameter() {
    public int getType() {
        return OracleTypes.CURSOR;
    }
};

m.url      = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@server.empresa.es:1522:SERV"
m.username = "user"
m.password = "pass"
m.driver   = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"

m.sql =Sql.newInstance(m.url, m.username, m.password, m.driver)


m.test={par ->

  def wresu=m.sql.callWithAllRows('{? = call core_utils.getCursor(?)}',[m.CURSOR_PARAMETER,par]) { ResultSet rs ->
    //
    println rs
    while (rs.next()) {
      println rs.getString("APLICACIO")
    }
  }
  wresu;
}
m.test("%BA%")
```